# Creating multiple combobox using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to create multiple Combobox that depend on each other and then write a label on the app based on the value of the selected combo box.
So from the code below, I want to select A1 to display "You selected A1" ... I am quite new to coding and there are probably better ways to write the code, but my brain just thinks of the problem this way. Thanks

```
    alpha = [
"A",
"B"
]

alpanum1 = [
"A1",
"A2"
]

alpanum2 = [
"B1",
"B2"
]            


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

roott = Tk()
roott.title('TEST')
roott.geometry("400x400")

def jj2(event):
    if j1.get() == alpha[0] and jo2.get() == alpanum1[0]:
    Jd = Label(roott, text = "You selected A1", font=('Times', 10, 'italic'), justify='left')
    Jd.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.1)
elif j1.get() == alpha[0] and jo2.get() == alpanum1[1]:
    Jd = Label(roott, text = "You selected A2", font=('Times', 10, 'italic'), justify='left')
    Jd.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2)
elif j1.get() == alpha[1] and jo2.get() == alpanum2[0]:
    Jd = Label(roott, text = "You selected B1", font=('Times', 10, 'italic'), justify='left')
    Jd.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3)
else:
    Jd = Label(roott, text = "You selected B2", font=('Times', 10, 'italic'), justify='left')
    Jd.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.4)
    
def jj1(event):
 if j1.get() == alpha[0]:
    jo2 = ttk.Combobox(roott, value=alpanum1)
    jo2.current()
    jo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",jj2)
    jo2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3)
                
else:
    jo2 = ttk.Combobox(roott, value=alpanum2)
    jo2.current()
    jo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", jj2)
    jo2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3)
                    



j1 = ttk.Combobox(roott, value=alpha)
j1.current(0)
j1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", jj1)
j1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)


roott.mainloop()
```

Comment: and what is the error

Comment: Does saying `global jo2` inside of your `jj1(event)` work?

Comment: Hey cool Cloud! There is no error message displayed. The code simply does not give any result.

Comment: The problem is the text. You selected A1 when A1 is selected and so forth should be displayed, but it is not.

Comment: I got `NameError: name 'jo2' is not defined` whenever I chose an item in `jo2`.  It is because `jo2` is a local variable in `jj1()` and it cannot be accessed inside `jj2()` function.  @CoolCloud suggestion of `global jo2` inside `jj1()` is one of the way to fix the issue.  However, your code create new instances of `jo2` and `jd` whenever selection of `j1` or `jo2` is changed.  It is not a correct design.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the suggestions @acw1668. What suggestion can you give to redesign the code better?

Comment: Also, I do not understand the global keyword reference can you clarify this?

Comment: `global jo2` tell Python to search for `jo2` in the global scope.  You should create `jo2` and `jd` once and update `values` of `jo2` whenever selection of `j1` is changed and update `jd` whenever selection of `jo2` is changed.

Comment: @LeonardOhenhen is the error solved?